# Validation field done without @valid annotation

Tags: spring-boot

I use spring boot 3.

Actually i use a resttemplate to call a service. In the service Payload have some field with @NotEmpty

```
@PostMapping(value="/persons")
public ResponseEntity<PersonPayload> subscripbePerson(@RequestBody PersonPayload person) throws ServiceSystemException {
   ...
}


public class PersonPayload {
    @NotEmpty
    private String phone;
}
```

I don't use @Valid annotation, and i get an error if i don't provide phone.

I was thinking in a class if we use @NotEmpty, that was validated only if we use @Valid